# swift - PDF417 capture problems

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, pdf417

I am trying to build a PDF417 code reader. I used the following tutorial and my code is working. http://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/

I have entered

```
for metadataObj in metadataObjects {
     print(metadataObj as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject)
}
```

the only output I am getting is

```
<AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject: 0x174039e00, type="org.iso.PDF417", bounds={ 0.3,0.5 0.6x0.2 }>corners { 0.3,0.5 0.3,0.6 0.9,0.6 0.9,0.5 }, time 408341268630291, stringValue "@ ANSI 990876030001DL"
```

how do I get it to give me the rest of the pdf417 data from the pdf417 barcode?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution?